# c# - Discord bot slash command build exception

Tags: c#, discord, bots, discord.net

I am trying to built discord slash command using guide from official discord.net documentation site. I`ve copied a code from this [article](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_basics/application-commands/slash-commands/creating-slash-commands.html) but in
`await client.CreateGlobalApplicationCommandAsync(globalCommand.Build());`
i get NullReferenceException, can anybody tell me what i do wrong?

p.s. i`ve remove code related with guild commands

Comment: You'll probably have to post your code so others can look at it in a code editor. Which line of code is returning the "NullReferenceException"? According to the documentation, your command should look like this: await client.Rest.CreateGuildCommand(guildCommand.Build(), guildId);